# Azure CDN purge fails with error InvalidResource"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cdn

CDN purge is working when I do it from azure portal but when I tried the same using arm api, it fails with

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResource",
    "message": "The resource format is invalid."
  }
}
```

Here's the api:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/{profileName}/endpoints/{endpointName}/purge?api-version=2016-10-02
```

I am able to do CDN Start, CDN load via API's except this purge which is my requirement :-(

Any help on this will be appreciated in tons :-)

Comment: CDN type is Standard Verizon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally after 62+ purge requests I found out that contentPaths in the request body had issues.

It should be this format

```
{
  "contentPaths": [
    "(String)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, was running in the same issue. Works perfect now